# Optimize update request in loop

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple use case, but it's really not optimized and I would like to know if it could be.

Let's say I have a simple entity that contains an `ID` and a variable named `price` (the entity is called `Product`).

I'm using `Hibernate` and `JPA` and every hour I would like to update my products' prices, so here is the pseudo code :

```
List<Product> products = Product.retrieveAll();
for (Product p : products) {
    p.price = makeSomeComplexComputationsToGetNextPrice();
    p.save();   // Updates the entity in the DB
}
```

This code is really simple. The `makeSomeComplexComputationsToGetNextPrice();`, makes some computations using the CPU, and it's fast.

When I have 100 products, everything is ok (the code makes 101 sql requests), but let's say I have 10 000 products, the code makes 10 001 sql requests, and it takes several seconds.

This use case is a simplified version of my real use case but the issue is here : when I have too many products, it takes too much time to execute (because of the huge number of queries).

Using `hibernate` and `JPA`, is there a way to optimize such a use case ? (This code should take less than a second to execute and it's taking much more than 1s because of all the queries)

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: `makeSomeComplexComputationsToGetNextPrice` is meant to use database access?

Comment: Why don't you try to first, retrieve from DB your data, and then querying/manipulating/calculating that data?

Comment: @Christian that's what OP's currently doing.

Comment: @Christian this is what i'm doing : retrieving the products, modifying variables and then updating them via sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a batch? That's typically how this is done, I think.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/batch.html

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to optimize is using bulk transfers. Try to compute a bulk of size N and then **store the whole N products at the same time**. Instead of making an effort for each storage (open connection, store, flush, close connection) you only do it **once for every bulk**.

Even more easier is when you choose the whole number of products as your bulksize, efficiently making it a load-computeeach-store algorithm.

Otherwise choosing the perfect bulk size may be tricky as it depends on a lot of parameters such as object size, your DB and its parameters hardware and so on, but usually a good value can be discovered just by trying out different values and measuring the time.

Other ways may include parallelism (doesn't seem proper as your IO is the bottleneck) or tuning your DB.

Comment: Thank you, but how to store the whole B products at the same time using Hibernate and JPA ?

Comment: You have to look at your table design, read some manuals or google your DB + bulk transfer. I'm no Hibernate or JPA expert, sorry. Usually it brings a lot performance if you bring your store method to exactly one open connection and exactly one close connection.

Answer (score 1):

As @EricStein and @LastFreeNickname pointed out, using bulk inserts, it is a solution if we are talking about INSERT commands at the `p.save();`
**But** if `makeSomeComplexComputationsToGetNextPrice();` is making a DB call for some SELECT requests then it makes sense to firstly query all needed data for those complex computations, and then operate on it (again using a batch technique for INSERTS).